# CSS Padding with ReactJS and static App.css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm building a simplified ecommerce app for my work in React with context API, and all of the functionality in JS is coming along and I understand it all. However, I only have basic CSS knowledge, and am using an App.css from a udemy MERN course by Brad Traversy. It's been super useful and convenient so far, but now I'm doing something that seems to be slightly out of the constraints of that app.css and have modified it a bit for sidebars. The sidebar is working nearly perfectly, but need to fix a slight display issue. Below are what I believe to be the relevant snippets of CSS and react, particularly the container class which is used in the main app.js to contain each of my 3 routes(though I'm only concerned with /pricequoter route & component for now).

Screenshot of the display issue, I'd like the sidebar to be aligned along the left side of the browser, and for it to be completely hidden on toggle.

[PriceQuoter.js sidebar toggled off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDSxl.png)

[PriceQuoter.js sidebar toggled on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGZnj.png)

First the react snippets

App.js snippet

```
           <div className='container'>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
                <Route exact path='/pricequoter' component={PriceQuoter} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
```

PriceQuoter.js component

```
        <div>
          <div className='grid-2'>
            <div>
              <CartSidebar width={300} height={"100vh"} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <ProductFilter /> <Products />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CartSidebar.js component

```
      <div
        className='side-bar'
        style={{
          transform: `translatex(${xPosition}px)`,
          width: width,
          minHeight: height,
        }}
      >
        (code for text of sidebar here)...
      </div>
```

And the relevant portions of app.css for the container, and sidebar class. I've tried removing the container class from app.js and this gets rid of the current display issue, but causes the right side of the page to run off the browser and require scrolling, as well as gets rid of the margins on both side of the app which I'd rather keep.

```
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  border: 1px;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.side-bar {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #d3d3d3;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: 0.8s ease;
}

.toggle-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 65px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20rem;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #009ca6;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Appreciate any and all help, and let me know if any other context/info would help!

Comment: as a general suggestion, i'd advise against combining css-in-js with css files; use one or the other so it's clear to anyone else reading the code where the styles live/are coming from

Comment: I definitely understand that! I'm looking to learn an alternative to app.css for whatever i develop next, but this was an early jumping board. Next week I'll look on refactoring to make the odd area where style elements are injected directly into the js into classes in app.css.

I also repurposed most of the sidebar component from an article and wasn't super sure on refactoring the style elements from the JS in there.